# Freemarker change a small double (like 0.0001) to zero when process a tempalte

Tags: freemarker

Freemarker version is 2.3.28

Here is the freemarker template

```
double value ${m.doubleValue}

StringValue value ${m.stringValue}
```

For the following code

```
public class TestDouble {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TemplateException {
    Configuration templateConfig;

    templateConfig = new Configuration(new Version(2, 3, 0));
    templateConfig.setClassLoaderForTemplateLoading(TestDouble.class.getClassLoader(), "ttt");
    templateConfig.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper(Configuration.DEFAULT_INCOMPATIBLE_IMPROVEMENTS));
    templateConfig.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);

    Map map = new HashMap();

    Map m = new HashMap();
    map.put("m",m);
    m.put("doubleValue", 0.001);
    m.put("stringValue", "0.0001");

    Template template = templateConfig.getTemplate("test.ftl");

    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4096);
    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(output);
    template.process(map, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    String ret = new String(output.toByteArray());

    System.out.println(ret);
  }
}
```

It will generate

```
double value 0.001

StringValue value 0.0001
```

But when change `doubleValue` to `0.0001`, the output would be

```
double value 0

StringValue value 0.0001
```

`0.0001` is replcaed as `0` in the output results. Is there some setting or format to leverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add number format configuration:

```
templateConfig.setNumberFormat("0.####");
```

And it should work, 'double value' printed `0` because it got converted to `1.0E-4`.